# Book request: PDE's in Mathematical Finance

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation, finance

**Background**:

I am an undergraduate maths student and I am tasked with writing a 10 page essay on a mathematical topic outside of what we studied yet, so something new and perhaps more advanced. The whole point of the essay is to get a student to learn about something new on his/her own by consulting various books.

Since my future interest lies in mathematical finance and since I enjoy Partial Differential Equations; I thought about choosing a topic concerning PDE's in finance. I have taken ODE's and PDE's undergraduate courses.

**Aim**: I would like to explore Brownian Motion, Black-Scholes Equation and topics such as Option Pricing and if I am not wrong I would have to learn about Stochastic Partial Differential Equations.
-How should I delve into this field? The issue I am having is that I do not really know which  areas of maths I actually have to learn in order to explore the above. Book recommendations would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: I would think (I could be wrong) that as an undergraduate, you would have difficulty understanding and learning stochastic PDEs in a short space of time especially if you have only taken undergraduate ODEs and PDEs courses.

Comment: @Mattos I understand that I cannot really learn stochastic PDE's thoroughly. Although what I am looking for is at least some part so I can discuss some topic(s) related to finance. Ordinary PDE's would also suffice but I am not sure if I can discuss them in financial topics without SPDE's...

Comment: There's also HJB equations and optimal control theory, a quite "natural" link to finance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For books on SPDEs in general you can look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867202/reference-complementing-hairers-introduction-to-stochastic-pdes/2867437#2867437). There is also my faviorite book on SPDEs, namely *PDE and Martingale Methods in Option Pricing* by Pasucci. I think it is exactly the book you are looking for. It is carefully explaining everything you'll need later to investigate SPDEs in mathematical finance. The Black-Scholes model is thoroughly discussed and many more market models. There are also numerical methods.

Otherwise if you want to focus more on ODEs I'd recommend *Stochastic Differential Equations* by Oksendal. Here, also all concepts are introduced in mathematically rigoros sense and in the last chapter several applications in mathematical finance are discussed, e.g. in option pricing.